# How to realize a smooth fibration as a subfibration of a product bundle?

Tags: differential-topology, homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles, fibration

Suppose $X\to M$ is a $C^\infty{}$-fibration. In his book Partial Differential Relation, Gromov claims (pg. 121) that this can be realized as a $C^\infty{}$-sub-fibration of the trivial bundle $M\times \mathbb{R}^m \to M$, for some large enough $m$. I fail to see how this is possible.

For the simpler case of a locally trivial fiber bundle $F\hookrightarrow X \to M$, my idea was to embed $F$ in an Euclidean space by Whitney and then use local triviality of the fiber bundle. But I got stuck defining the map on the total space.

Could someone please give me some idea or any reference for this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of a $C^\infty$ fibration?

Comment: @JackLee I would say every space is smooth manifold, projection is smooth map and each fiber is smooth manifold.

Comment: Are you sure? This applies to most smooth maps between smooth manifolds. For example, $\pi\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ given by $\pi(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ satisfies your criterion, but it's not a fibration by any definition I've ever seen.

Comment: @JackLee A smooth fibration is a fibration in the smooth category i.e it has homotopy lifting property and every map and space in question is smooth.